# UTF-8 don't run in r

Tags: r, utf-8

I've done everything but my r still doesn't bring the data in a correct way with this query.
I changed for utf8 in tools but nothing change
i changed the local too with this code

I can use parse_character, but i want put in default .

---

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    
system code page: 65001

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
_____
```

````
con <- function(database){[enter image description here][1]
      lapply(dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), dbDisconnect)
  cn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), host= "mysqlavisodados.servers", user = Sys.getenv("user"), password = Sys.getenv("password"),dbname = database )
    if(Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")!="Portuguese_Brazil.1252"){dbSendQuery(cn, "SET CHARSET 'utf8';")}
  return(cn)
}

queryEstagio <- paste0("
SELECT 
v.vag_id as vag_id,
v.titulo,
empresa_cont,
tipo,
CONVERT(especializacao USING utf8) as Escolaridade,
periodo,
CONVERT( horario USING utf8) as horario,
qtde,
v.data_entrada
FROM conline.vag as v
left join conlina.vag_cidade as c on c.vag_id = v.vag_id
    left join conlina.cidade as cd on cd.cidade_id = c.cidade_id
        left join conlina.cidade as cidade on cidade.cidade_id = cd.cidade_id
        left join conlina.estado as e on  e.estado_id = cd.estado_id
    left join conlina.emp as emp on v.emp_id = emp.emp_id
left join conlina.faixasal_vag as sal on v.faixasal_id = sal.faixasal_id 
    where v.vag_id in (",vaga_id,") and
    (v.titulo like '%auxiliar%' or 
    v.titulo like '%motorista%' or
    v.titulo like '%cozinheiro%' or
    v.titulo like '%estagio%' or
    v.titulo like '%estagiario%'or
    v.titulo like '%ajudante%'   
    
")

vag_inicio <- dbGetQuery(conn = con("conlina"), queryEstagio)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzzoR.png
````

Comment: Did you try `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = ".utf8")`? Upgrade to `R version 4.2.0`…

Comment: Which operating system? Note: the `.1252` in your locale is about Windows CP 1252, so not a UTF-8 encoding. And please note: locale names are not very standardized (so different OSes may use different name. For sure your locale doesn't follow modern internet standards (but also not yet widely used on some operating system)

Comment: PS: R has a FAQ, and it has (if it was not removed) a section on how to use UTF-8 in different systems.